# How to set a value of nest object value in onChange event

Tags: reactjs, object

I'm trying to set a value of nested object value for the onChange event.

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
            fullname: '',
            email:
            address: {
                fhbca: '',
                street: '',
                landmark: '',
                pincode: '',
            }
        });

onChange={(e) => { setState({...state, address.fhbca : e.target.value }) }} **<--**
```

When setting the value of **address.fhbca**. Using this above statement throws errors **Accounts.jsx: Unexpected token, expected "," (120:100)**. Please correct me and suggest.
how to set a value of this **address.fhbca** ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do like this

```
onChange={(e) => { setState(({...state, address: {...state.address, fhbca: e.target.value} }})}}
```